# Handle error and resume observable simultaneously in Rx

Tags: android, error-handling, rx-java

I write an Android app which fetches data from a server when network connection is OK and gets it from a local DB otherwise. So conceptually I have:

```
networkObservable.onErrorResumeNext(dbObservable).subscribe(...);
```

But if `networkObservable` encounters an error I would also like to inform the user about conncetion problems; not just resume DB observable.

But now it seems to me that either I resume dbObservable or I report that an error occured in `Subscriber`'s `onError()` method. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add `.doOnError()` before `.onErrorResumeNext()`:

```
networkObservable
    .doOnError(informTheUser())
    .onErrorResumeNext(dbObservable)
    .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea! But the observable construction code resides in the Model's code (MVP pattern). The layer should not be aware of a user and how to handle error situations in terms of interface.
At the same time Presenter (who gets the observable and subscribes to it) should not now about DB's or network's existance.
So that's a little restrication on acceptable solutions. A perfect one would be where we replace the `networkObservable` with `dbObservable`  and still allow the subscriber to know that `networkObservable` failed preserving the exact reason of the fail (`Throwable`).

Comment: I see, that feels like a contradiction to me. At the same time you want to hide from the presenter network's existence, but you also want to notify it about a network error. Anyway, a solution might be to have another observable just to emit network errors. It could be a subject and you could call it's `onNext()` in `doOnError()`. Second solution would be emit objects that hold both your data and the throwable.

Comment: Your first solution is really good. I'll use a `Subject` which Model will use in order to inform Presenter layer about network failures. I'll post the solution code for the community soon. Thank you, Marcin!

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem might be the following:

```
return networkObservable.onErrorResumeNext(
            Observable.concat(
                    dbObservable, Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Data>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Subscriber<? super Data> subscriber) {
                            subscriber.onNext(null);
                        }
                    })
            )
    );
```

The subscriber can react to the null value and report that something went wrong with loading data. However in this solution precise information about error is lost. We replace the `Throwable` with just `null`.